# Making Universal ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am in the process of developing a universal iOS app.

What I want is for all my views to automatically resize depending on the screen sisze, I mean I dont want to hard code any `CGRect` sizes or use Interface Builder; I am using a specific app example but I would very much appreciate an answer that is usable in many similar scenarios.

This is a very simple app but I hope the answer can show me how to go about doing this for all my views, so they can adjust to any size.

For this specific app I am building something that will look like this:

[image: A simple mockup of a screen used in my app.]

This is a particularly tricky example as the MKMapView has to be initialized with a frame but I hope you can help me.

The first problem I ran into was the fact that in my loadView method:

```
MKMapView *mapView=[[MKMapView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    mapView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

    self.view=mapView;
```

The autoresizing mask does not work unless the view controller is managed by a `UINavigationController`; I do not know why.

The next problem comes when I want to add my UIToolbar at the bottom of the screen.

In order to get this I do the following:

```
UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 420, 320, 40)];

toolBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

[self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

This works perfectly with an iPhone but it does not with an iPad (the toolbar's width is adjusted but it obviously is no loger at the bottom of the screen) as the size is hard coded.

Sorry for posting such a long question but I think the answers can be a great resource for me and other developers in need.

Please tell me If I am not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the functions defined in [`CGGeometry`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html) are useful when dealing with iOS view geometry.

Say you wanted to take the entire frame and divide into two parts. The bottom part should be the toolbar frame which sits at the bottom of the screen, and is 44 px high. The remaining portion at the top should all be given to the map. A useful function for doing this is `CGRectDivide` which is defined as:

```
void CGRectDivide (
   CGRect rect,
   CGRect *slice,
   CGRect *remainder,
   CGFloat amount,
   CGRectEdge edge
);
```

You pass it the full CGRect, two uninitialized CGRect's that will get populated with the correct frame sizes after dividing, an edge (left, right, top, bottom) from which to start, and the distance from that edge.

Playing with unicode art, this is the best I can do. The full rect is divided into two parts. The black lines at the bottom is the toolbar's frame. The white rectangles is the frame that the map gets.

```
▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫
▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫
▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫
▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫
▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫
▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫
▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫
▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫
▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫
▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫
▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫▫
■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
```

```
CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

CGRect mapFrame, toolbarFrame;
CGRectDivide(appFrame, &toolbarFrame, &mapFrame, 44, CGRectMaxYEdge);

// map is an MKMapView
map.frame = mapFrame;
// toolbar is a UIToolbar
toolbar.frame = toolbarFrame;
```

Here's how it looks on the iPhone and iPad simulators.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

When I try the code I get the frames pushed down 20 points consistently, both on the iPhone and the iPad.

Do you have any idea why this may happen?

Comment: I got it to work using CGRectDivide(appFrame, &toolbarFrame, &mapFrame, 64, 3 ); Using 64 instead of 44.

Comment: that's the 20 pixels of status bar.

Comment: It makes sense that the status bar is the 20 px but when I ask for the appFrame it returns a frame that is 460x320, not 480x320, so I do not get why the CGREctDivide would take the status bar under consideration if it is not taken into consideration by the app frame. I am having a hard time understanding why this is.
Could you post the complete method you used to get the resulting screenshots using 44 instead of 64?

Comment: @Zebs - here's the method I am using - http://pastie.org/1586695. `applicationFrame` has a size of `320x460`, but its origin is at `0,20`, not, `0,0`. That's the reason why that 20px offset shows up. In the pasted code, I am using the bounds of the window frame, to ensure origin is at `0,0` and inside the window's local coordinate system. Also, if you can paste the code, it will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand where the 20 px are coming from!

I have it working perfectly by setting the origin to 0 -[http://pastie.org/1587939](http://pastie.org/1587939)

BTW, the company I work at is looking for developers on stack overflow, this is the [link](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/10255/ios-android-balckberry-and-php-developers-zebas-studios)

Answer (score 1):

For the toolbar you can work out its frame like this:

```
CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
CGRect toolbarFrame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(applicationFrame), CGRectGetMaxY(applicationFrame) - 44.0, applicationFrame.size.width, 44.0)
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:toolbarFrame];
```

If your UIToolbar shouldn't extend the width of the screen, but instead a view, just set applicationFrame to the frame of that view.